# Contiguous Sub Array solution in O(n)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Recently I came across a problem stating that there is an array of integers and we will be given a wildcard number. We need to look through the array and form a sub array such that

1. The wildcard number should be the last element of the sub array (i.e
   : {2,3,4} is valid if 4 is wild card number but {2,4,3} is invalid).
2. All the elements before the wild card number should be less than
   that. (i.e : {2,3,4} is valid if 4 is wild card number but {5,2,4}
   is invalid).
3. The wild card number should not be clubbed between two sub arrays.

The output should return the length of such sub arrays.

Example problem :
If the array is {4,5,6,4,3,2,4,8,2,4} and the wild card number is 4 the ouput should be 7. (Because the sub arrays are {4}, {4}, {3,2,4}, {2,4}).

I have written the code for the problem. But what I need to know is whether the solution can be written in O(n) time complexity. Also is there a way to find the best time complexity possible by looking at the problem alone.

Code snippet:

```
private static void solution(int[] array, int k)
    {
        int forwardCounter = 0;
        int backwardCounter = 0;
        int length = 0;

        while(forwardCounter != array.length)
        {
            if(array[forwardCounter] == k)
            {
                length++;
                backwardCounter = forwardCounter - 1;
                while(backwardCounter >= 0)
                {
                    if(backwardCounter >= 0 && array[backwardCounter--] < k)
                    {
                        length++;
                    }
                    else
                        break;
                }
            }
            forwardCounter++;
        }
        System.out.println(length);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        solution(new int[]{4,5,6,4,3,2,4,8,2,4}, 4);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is linear, but your array is going to be traversed two times in the worst case. The worst case obviously happens when
-array is sorted in ascending order
-wildcard number is the last (i.e. largest) element of array

Your solution can be modified in the way to prevent backward traversal and use forward traversal only.

Comment: Thanks mangusta. But is there a way to find the best fit complexity for a particular problem by looking at the problem statement alone?

Comment: It depends on the problem. For example comparison sort has been proven to have complexity `omega(nlogn)` i.e. there is no way of solving it in shorter time. I think most of the problems can be shown to have some minimal amount of time for solving them (given the statement alone)